# Magnific popup set type from data attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, magnific-popup

I am trying to setup mixed content types gallery like this , 
http://codepen.io/dimsemenov/pen/vKrqs

but I would like to read the type dynamically from the elements markup instead of writing up the links and types in js.

```
<a class="lightbox" data-type="image" href="imagethumb" >
    <img src="fullimage">
</a>
<a class="lightbox" data-type="iframe" href="iframelink">
    Iframe link
</a>
```

Is there a way to set popup type by reading the element data attribute ,

something like

```
$(".lightbox").magnificPopup({
    type: $(this).attr('data-type'),
    mainClass: 'mfp-with-zoom',


    zoom: {
        enabled: true,
        duration: 300,
        easing: 'ease-in-out',
        opener: function (openerElement) {
            return openerElement.is('img') ? openerElement : openerElement.find('img');
        }
    },
    gallery: {
        enabled: true
    }
});
```

any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

This is solved via

```
mfp-type
```

css class 
http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/documentation.html#content-types

or this combo
https://github.com/dimsemenov/Magnific-Popup/issues/146#issuecomment-20729036